# Is "doing a Batman cosplay" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language, light-verbs

Is "doing a Batman cosplay" idiomatic? Googling it seems to return a few results, but I am not sure if it's idiomatic, because cosplay is a relatively new word and it doesn't really sound natural. Is there a better and more idiomatic way of saying it?

Comment: I think you could improve this question by providing a longer example sentence showing how you might use the phrase. (For example, "This weekend, I'll be doing a Batman cosplay," or "I don't mind going to Comicons, but I don't like doing a Batman cosplay.") Maybe the phrase sounds good in some contexts but odd in others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no other verb seems to fit (or we can't think of the right word) English speakers often fall back on "do".

> He **does** a good impersonation of that famous actor.
>
> They **do** a nice barbecue at that restaurant.
>
> I heard my favorite singer is going to **do** a performance at my university.

In that context, it's not wrong to say "do a cosplay":

> For ComicCon this year, I'm going to **do** a Batman cosplay.

However, be aware that "cosplay" is itself a verb:

> For ComicCon this year, I'm going to **cosplay** as Batman.